# 2.7 CSV module wants unicode, but doesn't want unicode

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, unicode, error-handling

```
csvfile_ = open(finishedFileName+num+".csv","w",newline='')
writ = csv.writer(csvfile_, dialect='excel')
firstline = unicode(str(firstline))
try:
    writ.writerow(firstline)
except TypeError:
    print firstline
    print type(firstline)
    raise
```

I get a `TypeError: must be unicode, not str` with this code. When printing the type of firstline, I see `<type 'unicode'>`. When I print firstline, I see `['project_number', 'project_location']`(The list is longer than that, but it continues in that style.)

This program was working fine in python 3.3. I ported it over with 3to2, switching from unix to windows as I did so.

How do I make this program write smoothly?

Note: This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input according to the official documentation, but it told me to give it Unicode input anyway.

Full exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 382, in <module>
    process(marketingLogExportFileName)
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 123, in process
    writing(csvfile,modified,firstline)
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 114, in writing
    writ.writerow(firstline)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

If I take out the code to make firstline unicode, I instead get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 382, in <module>
    process(marketingLogExportFileName)
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 123, in process
    writing(csvfile_,modified,firstline)
  File "C:\Users\urightswt\Downloads\LogModToConvert.py", line 114, in writing
    writ.writerow(firstline)
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: You are looking at only the *exception*; remove the `TypeError` and look at the full traceback.

Comment: The `csv` module in Python 2.7 is documented as **not** supporting unicode.

Comment: What is `csvfile_`? Is it an open file object opened with the `io` or `codecs` module, that auto-encodes Unicode? If so, then it is **that** file object that expects Unicode, not the CSV module. Please show us the code that opens the file object.

Comment: and `open` is imported from where? The *built-in* `open()` function does not accept a `newline` parameter on Python 2.

Comment: And my apologies; I didn't immediately realize that both the `csv` module and the open file object are both implemented in C, so the traceback is not very informative, indeed.

Comment: Try unicodecsv. It wraps CSV with unicode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters open is imported from io. This was one of the changes 3to2 made. Should I remove the traceback information?

Comment: @DivinusVox I will if I have to, but so far it is in pure python, and if possible I would like to keep it that way when I pass it on to the programmer after me.

Comment: csv must always be utf8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, `3to2` used the `io.open()` call instead of the built-in Python 2 `open()` function. This opened the file in text mode, which like on Python 3 expects Unicode input.

However, the *`csv` module* does not support Unicode data; it certainly does not produce Unicode.

You'll either have to open the file in binary mode on Python 2:

```
mode = 'w'
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    mode += 'b'
csvfile_ = open(finishedFileName + num + ".csv", mode, newline='')
```

or use the built-in `open()` call instead:

```
csvfile_ = open(finishedFileName + num + ".csv", 'wb')
```

where you have to use `'wb'` as the mode anyway.

If you are trying to write out unicode data, you'll have to encode that data *before* passing it to the `csv.writer()` object. The [`csv` module examples section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) includes code to make encoding from Unicode before writing a little easier.

Comment: I was trying to write a CSV processing program which should run with either Python 2 or Python 3 and I found this answer (found via search engine) to be helpful. I'm surprised to be the first user to upvote it.

Comment: Could it be that you missed `from future.builtins import open` in the first snippet? I think `newline` is not in Python 2 open.

Comment: @moose: that's the whole point of the answer; see also the comments on the question. The import is `from io import open`; `future_builtins` doesn't include `open`. I offered options to make the code `3to2` compatible.

Comment: @moose: so in other words: in **Python 3** you'd not have an import statement for the `open()` call; it is the `3to2` tool that would add that in.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Pieters' solution using 'w' or 'wb' does not seem to work because of the newline argument. I personally get a ValueError.

```
ValueError: binary mode doesn't take a newline argument
```

Which I don't really understand, I would expect `io` to ignore it rather than raise an Exception.
The only solution that works for me both on python 2 and 3 is:

```
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    open(my_csv_file, 'rb')
else:
    open(my_csv_file, 'r', newline='')
```

Solution that can become very heavy when you open a lot of files. Martijn solution was cleaner in that regard, if only it could work!

**EDIT:**
I think the cleanest working solution when developing a package that needs to read/write files often is to create a small utility function that can be called everywhere in the package:

```
import sys
import io

def open_csv_rb(my_file):
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        return io.open(my_file, 'rb')
    else:
        return io.open(my_file, 'r', encoding='utf8')

def open_csv_wb(my_file):
    if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
        return io.open(my_file, 'wb')
    else:
        return io.open(my_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with open() and csv.  A friend gave me the solution, which is to use open_output() instead of open().  open_output() defaults to "wb" instead of text.