# u2013 error with openpyxl - python 2.7

Tags: python, excel

I am using python2.7. I can't use python 3. I wrote this to convert an excel spreadsheet to csv.  It is throwing an error for "u2013'" which is an 'en dash' character. In perl - you can load a file in unicode with the open command, but I don't know how to do that in python.

```
#!/home/casper/python/core/2.7.14/exec/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('RiskLimitSnapshot.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
with open('goodRiskLimitSnapshot.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/casper/pyExceltoCSV", line 16, in <module>
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 74: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I changed the script to use io.open:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DailyETRiskLimitSnapshot.xlsx' ,   data_only=True)
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
    with io.open('goodDailyETRiskLimitSnapshot.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

However it is throwing a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyExceltoCVS.py", line 20, in <module>
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('DailyETRiskLimitSnapshot.xlsx',encoding_override="cp1252") I am looking for some feature like this - encode the excel at the load_workbook function

Comment: *"I am getting an error for a "u'\u2013'" which I think is the symbol for a hyphen"* U+2013 is the Unicode code point for EN DASH, but I don't know what you mean by the extra `u` and single quotes.

Comment: Edited out Borodin - it was in the error code from python, however probably should not be in the title.

Comment: There is only one tab in the excel spreadsheet - there are not multiple workbooks in one sheet.

Comment: your problem isn't the read - that is working correctly, and loading unicode. You just need to figure out how to write unicode to a csv. For that, use `cell.value.decode()` to go from str to unicode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try ?

```
#!/home/casper/python/core/2.7.14/exec/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('RiskLimitSnapshot.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
with open('goodRiskLimitSnapshot.csv', 'wb') as f: 
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow(unicode([cell.value for cell in r]))
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to open a file for encoded output is to use the `io` module:

```
import io

with io.open('goodRiskLimitSnapshot.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f: 
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

Comment: Throws an error -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyth_excelCVS.py", line 20, in <module>
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `pandas`:

```
wb = pd.read_excel('RiskLimitSnapshot.xlsx') #you can specify the sheet name using sheetname argument
wb.to_csv('goodRiskLimitSnapshot.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Alternatively you can use `codecs` and do:

```
codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: We have panda in the list of approved modules  -- never seen it in use, and don't know how to use it.

Comment: panda is not linked to python3.* and this box only has python2.7

Comment: @casper Just to be clear, you tried `import codecs` and it didn't work?

Comment: This is a highly controlled work environment (greetings to those in InfoSec now reading this message). You can't import your own modules or make your own configurations - to perl or python. The process to get a module added is lengthly and goes to a managing director for approval. Basically people here just use what is already approved.

Answer (score 1):

Python3 makes lot of things easier by using the default encoding as unicode. But in Python2 you get a default `str` and different `unicode` representation

Now consider the case of `en-dash` = `–`, looks similar to a normal `-` but is not.

Let's fire up a python 2.7 console and see the difference

```
>>> val_str = '–'
>>> val_str
'\xe2\x80\x93'
```

Above is how an `en-dash` is represented by a `str`. While for `unicode`

```
>>> val_unicode = u'–'
>>> val_unicode
u'\u2013'
```

Now let's try and write these to a `csv` file using different combinations

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import io

val_str = '–'
val_unicode = u'–'


def try_writing_csv(filename, data, mode='w', **kwargs):
    try:
        with io.open(filename, mode=mode, **kwargs) as f:
            c = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
            c.writerow([data])
    except Exception, ex:
        print("failed to write - " + filename)


try_writing_csv("ascii1.csv", val_str)
try_writing_csv("ascii2.csv", val_str, encoding="utf8")
try_writing_csv("ascii3.csv", val_str.decode('utf8'), encoding="utf8")

try_writing_csv("unicode1.csv", val_unicode)
try_writing_csv("unicode2.csv", val_unicode, encoding="utf8")
try_writing_csv("unicode3.csv", val_unicode.encode('utf8'), encoding="utf8")
```

And now let's  run the same

```
failed to write - ascii1.csv
failed to write - ascii2.csv
failed to write - ascii3.csv
failed to write - unicode1.csv
failed to write - unicode2.csv
failed to write - unicode3.csv
```

The results are overwhelming as all the method fails. So we need look at what is wrong with it. Let's make some more trials

```
try_writing_csv("ascii4.csv", val_str.decode('utf8'), mode="wb")
try_writing_csv("ascii5.csv", val_str, mode="utf8")
try_writing_csv("ascii6.csv", val_str.decode('utf8').encode('utf8'), mode="wb")

try_writing_csv("unicode4.csv", val_unicode, mode="wb")
try_writing_csv("unicode5.csv", val_unicode.encode('utf8'), mode='wb')
```

And now out run would give an output

```
failed to write - ascii1.csv
failed to write - ascii2.csv
failed to write - ascii3.csv
failed to write - ascii4.csv
failed to write - ascii5.csv
failed to write - unicode1.csv
failed to write - unicode2.csv
failed to write - unicode3.csv
failed to write - unicode4.csv
```

So `ascii6.csv` and `unicode.csv` was actually successful. Let's check the files also

[image: CSV file]

and looks like we did get then right for both the files. So the final two statements which worked are below

```
try_writing_csv("ascii6.csv", val_str.decode('utf8').encode('utf8'), mode="wb")
try_writing_csv("unicode5.csv", val_unicode.encode('utf8'), mode='wb')
```

So the key learnings

- Don't use `encoding=utf8` while opening the file
- Use binary mode for writing the file
- If it is a `str` then `decode` as `utf8` and then encode as `utf8`
- If it is a `unicode` then `encode` as `utf8`

And then now comes the explanation time, which you can get from the below SO thread

[2.7 CSV module wants unicode, but doesn't want unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449233/2-7-csv-module-wants-unicode-but-doesnt-want-unicode)

> If you are trying to write out unicode data, you'll have to encode that data *before* passing it to the `csv.writer()` object. The [`csv` module examples section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) includes code to make encoding from Unicode before writing a little easier.

Comment: This is very good - I still have to work out the broad strokes. I still can't get the script to work.

Comment: Try with `cp1252` as the encoding while opening the file

Comment: Yeah - I tried the windows encoding early on - no dice.

Comment: If you can share the file, I can give it a shot

Comment: @capser, if you don't share more details it would difficult to sort your problem out and also the bounty is about to expire

Answer (score 0):

Python2 csv library does not support well unicode.
Have you considerd using the libraries [unicodecsv](https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/0.11.2/) or [backports.csv](https://github.com/ryanhiebert/backports.csv) ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

That error tells you that you are trying to write python unicode object to file and default ASCII codec cant encode it. Encode called implicitly to convert python string/unicode objects to bytes. You should do it yourself with needed encoding - `utf-8` in your case:

Change that line:

```
c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

to:

```
c.writerow([cell.value.encode('utf-8') for cell in r])
```

Without explicitly specifying needed encoding default is used and your variant of writerow call can be writed as: `c.writerow([cell.value.encode('ascii') for cell in r])` and of course will raise `UnicodeEncodeError` because you have unicode string.

You can check your default encoding with this code:

```
import sys
sys.getdefaultencoding()
```